# can we use Existing Entities for Entity Framework rather than EF generated Entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, domain-driven-design, entities

Can i use Entities  that are already a part of my project ***as Entity Framework Entities***.

My project Follows Domain Driven Design that do contain all entities that represents my database tables.

I do not  want Entity Framework to generate new entities from my existing database, rather i want it to use existing entities in my project.

when ever i use my existing Entities in DB Context Class like this:

```
        public DbSet<SomeOtherProjectInSoulution.ChequeBookRequestAuditLog> ChequeBookRequestAuditLogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SomeOtherProjectInSoulution.OfflinePayOrderRequestAuditLogEntity> OfflinePayOrderRequestAuditLogEntities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SomeOtherProjectInSoulution.FundsTransferAuditLogEntity> FundsTransferAuditLogEntities { get; set; }
```

it Gives me the following Error:

***The entity type FundsTransferAuditLogEntity is not part of the model for the current 
context.***

Even though these entities are **EXACT Replica** of entities that were created by Entity Framework but i deleted them

DB Context:

```
public partial class PRISMEntitiesTest : DbContext
{
    public PRISMEntitiesTest()
        : base("name=PRISMEntitiesTest")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<Application.Domain.AuditLog.ChequeBookRequestAuditLog> ChequeBookRequestAuditLogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Application.Domain.AuditLog.OfflinePayOrderRequestAuditLogEntity> OfflinePayOrderRequestAuditLogEntities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Application.Domain.AuditLog.FundsTransferAuditLogEntity> FundsTransferAuditLogEntities { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please, show a little more code of how you're defining your `DbContext` class. What you're trying to do is simply "EF Code First" and I have been using it without any problem at all. You can define your own POCOs, and use them to define your Code First model.

Comment: @JotaBe I fixed the Problem somehow but every time i make a little change in my designer view ... Db Context code is regenerated which removes the reference to these POCOs that i define explicitly.
any solution to above problem?

Comment: What is your DB context constructor?

Comment: @marianoc84: Added in question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this constructor, to your class:

```
public PRISMEntitiesTest(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : this(nameOrConnectionString, new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<PRISMEntitiesTest>()) { }
```

[DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/gg679604%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) is *an implementation of IDatabaseInitializer that will DELETE, recreate, and optionally re-seed the database only if the model has changed since the database was created.*

This is usefull in coding phase, since you can ignore schema issues.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, when you make a change in the model, the entity (the class) changes, and the EF model doesn't match with the DB. The first time a `DbContext` is initialized in an application it checks if the EF model matches the DB. If you update the model, and don't update the DB you'll get an exception.

One alternative is marianoc84 answer: drop and create the DB on all iterations, but I must propose a cleaner solution:

1. forget the model that you have in the designer view
2. use pure EF Code First, i.e. define the model using code, not a diagram
3. use Migrations

You can do the task 1 by deleting it. Yep, delete the model. You're using DDD, you don't need that

For the step 2, you can use something like "EF Reverse POCO Code First Generator". This will allow you to create one or several Code First models from your DB (i.e. create pure POCO classes, and the Code First configuration for them, like column types and sizes, keys, relations...). When you get used to this way of working, you'll see that it matches DDD in a better way, because, instead of modifying a diagram, you'll directly modify an entity (class) and can move that changes to the DB (that's the step 3)

Setp 3: If you use marianoc84 solution, and have only one DbContext, you don't need to take this step. If you have several context,or don't want to drop and create the DB whenever you start your app, then you can use Migrations. With Migrations you can evolve the Code First model and apply the changes to the DB in a non-destructive way. Basically you make to enable migrations and create an "Initial Migration" in the initial moment when the DbContext and the DB schemas match in their original state. You'll see a file created in a "Migrations" folder in your project. From this point on, you can change the classes in your DbContext, and create new Migrations. Each migration have "instructions" on how to modify the DB schema from the previous migration to the recently created (Up) and vice versa (Down), and you have to give it a name. When you want to update the database, you simply have to do run an `Update-Database` command, which, by default, will update your DB to match the last migration.

In fact Migrations are much more powerful: they allow to move up and donw from migration to migration, apply the changes directly in the DB, be suctomized, generate a SQL Script to update the DB... Google for EF Migrations and you'll find a lot of examples on how you use it. But perhaps [this is the best information available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621.aspx).

NOTE: the new EF release which is being developed, and will be probably named "Entity Framework 7", won't have the option to define the DB as a diagram: [it will be compulsory to use Code First](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx), and there are good reasons for it. You can get plenty of info about this in the [ADO.NET blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/).

Comment: I do not use diagram to define model. My Project Already had Entities that looked like DB Entities (except for few additional fields that my DB does not have)

I then thought to introduce Entity Fraework to my Project so i created an ADO.NET Entity model using EF 5 and once i created it (bringing only few entities from my DB) i DELETED the entities it created and changed the context file so that the entities that it defined  referenced MY already present entities in Project .
Is that a fine CODE FIRST approach?

Comment: also the entities that i define DO have some additional fields that my DB tables do not have . ... Does that mean that i can never ever use migrations for those Entities if i do not want these additional fields to be added in my table?

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe not... ;) There are several solutions. I think this is important enough to create a new question. Let me know if you do so, and I'll give you some of the possible solutions. Noone told that implementing DDD was easy, but it has it rewards. The question is not that I don't want to answer in a comment: the question is that this requires more explanation that what can be done here, and if it's on a separate question, it will be much more useful for the community.

Comment: i will surely make another question and ping u here, :)